# How do I use bind values in a PostgreSQL UPDATE statement?

Tags: perl, postgresql, prepared-statement

For my UPDATE statement on PostgreSQL (from Perl via `DBI` and `DBD::Pg`) I want to bind a value like this:

```
my $sql = 'UPDATE mytable SET foo = % WHERE id = 42';
my $foo_value = 23;
$dbh->do($sql, {}, $foo_value);
```

This gives the following error in the `do()` line:

```
DBD::Pg::db do failed: called with 1 bind variable when 0 are needed at...
```

I tried other syntaxes for placeholders, `$1` and `?`. Both fail with

```
DBD::Pg::db do failed: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "" at...
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `?` character is the correct placeholder.

```
my $sql = 'UPDATE mytable SET foo = ? WHERE id = 42';
my $foo_value = 23;
$dbh->do($sql, undef, $foo_value);
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The placeholder confusion obscured the problem that my `$foo_value` was not a numeric value in my unit test.

Comment: @Stefan: Also see http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values